# REST API: JSON objects in URL to get custom JSON

Tags: java, json, url, cs-cart

I am using the cs-cart rest API to create an android app. My problem is that i want categories as needed for example the parent category has an id "0", so i want just that category, can i edit URL to get only the categories whose parent_id: "0"

http://www.example.com/api/categories

I also tried URL encoding with different online tools, neither worked.

it's the JSON i am getting right now, i need the specific parent_id.

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "category_id": "735",
            "parent_id": "755",
            "id_path": "60/755/735",
            "category": "Clocks",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "1",
            "seo_name": "watches",
            "seo_path": "60/755"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "682",
            "parent_id": "295",
            "id_path": "217/295/682",
            "category": "360° Video Camera",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "514",
            "seo_name": "360-video-camera",
            "seo_path": "217/295"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "413",
            "parent_id": "0",
            "id_path": "413",
            "category": " Apparel",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "2",
            "seo_name": "apparel",
            "seo_path": ""
        },
        {
            "category_id": "359",
            "parent_id": "217",
            "id_path": "217/359",
            "category": "Computers ",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "25",
            "seo_name": "computer-cables",
            "seo_path": "217"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "357",
            "parent_id": "344",
            "id_path": "217/344/357",
            "category": "Chargers",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "1154",
            "seo_name": "network-media-converters",
            "seo_path": "217/344"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "355",
            "parent_id": "344",
            "id_path": "217/344/355",
            "category": "Cellphones",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "1469",
            "seo_name": "gateways-controllers",
            "seo_path": "217/344"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "345",
            "parent_id": "344",
            "id_path": "217/344/345",
            "category": "Bluetooth Accessories",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "1052",
            "seo_name": "network-antennas",
            "seo_path": "217/344"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "298",
            "parent_id": "295",
            "id_path": "217/295/298",
            "category": "Camera Accessories",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "507",
            "seo_name": "camera-accessories",
            "seo_path": "217/295"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "296",
            "parent_id": "295",
            "id_path": "217/295/296",
            "category": "Camcorders",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "504",
            "seo_name": "camcorders",
            "seo_path": "217/295"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "295",
            "parent_id": "217",
            "id_path": "217/295",
            "category": "Cameras & Camcorders",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "0",
            "seo_name": "cameras-and-camcorders",
            "seo_path": "217"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "271",
            "parent_id": "218",
            "id_path": "217/218/271",
            "category": "Audio Amplifiers",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "1003",
            "seo_name": "audio-amplifiers",
            "seo_path": "217/218"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "238",
            "parent_id": "218",
            "id_path": "217/218/238",
            "category": "Bluetooth Music Receivers",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "519",
            "seo_name": "bluetooth-music-receivers",
            "seo_path": "217/218"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "218",
            "parent_id": "217",
            "id_path": "217/218",
            "category": "Audio & Home Theatre",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "1",
            "seo_name": "audio-and-home-theatre",
            "seo_path": "217"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "188",
            "parent_id": "779",
            "id_path": "776/779/188",
            "category": "Baby Furniture",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "430",
            "seo_name": "baby-furniture",
            "seo_path": "776/779"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "185",
            "parent_id": "779",
            "id_path": "776/779/185",
            "category": "Baby Travel",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "494",
            "seo_name": "baby-travel",
            "seo_path": "776/779"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "169",
            "parent_id": "779",
            "id_path": "776/779/169",
            "category": "Baby Bathing & Potting",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "405",
            "seo_name": "baby-bathing-and-potting",
            "seo_path": "776/779"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "109",
            "parent_id": "108",
            "id_path": "101/108/109",
            "category": "BD/DVD Movies",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "0",
            "seo_name": "bd-dvd-movies",
            "seo_path": "101/108"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "90",
            "parent_id": "85",
            "id_path": "60/85/90",
            "category": "Cups & Mugs",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "504",
            "seo_name": "cups-and-mugs",
            "seo_path": "60/85"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "83",
            "parent_id": "69",
            "id_path": "60/69/83",
            "category": "Ceiling Lights",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "592",
            "seo_name": "ceiling-lighting",
            "seo_path": "60/69"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "70",
            "parent_id": "69",
            "id_path": "60/69/70",
            "category": " Bulbs & Tubes ",
            "position": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "product_count": "504",
            "seo_name": "bulbs",
            "seo_path": "60/69"
        }
    ],
    "params": {
        "category_id": 0,
        "visible": false,
        "current_category_id": 0,
        "simple": false,
        "plain": true,
        "limit": 0,
        "item_ids": "",
        "group_by_level": false,
        "get_images": false,
        "category_delimiter": "/",
        "get_frontend_urls": false,
        "max_nesting_level": null,
        "get_company_name": false,
        "items_per_page": 20,
        "page": 1,
        "except_id": 414,
        "sort_order": "asc",
        "sort_by": "position",
        "sort_order_rev": "desc",
        "total_items": "557"
    }
}
```

Comment: well!! It depends,  if server side allows you to filter categories by parent Id than you could. Otherwise you need to iterate over all of the results and filter it.

Comment: there are more than 500 categories and more than million of products, how to configure them? this will slow the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only the categories whose parent_id is 0 in your API call, please use the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/api/categories?category_id=0&visible=true
```

Of course, any other id can be used instead of 0, just make sure you add the `&visible=true` parameter.

Comment: brother, you are great. Well, what here visible param show, also one more question why we use category_id=0, instead of parent_id=0?

Comment: That's like you're getting information about a category with an ID of 0. It just happens that the only information API can provide you about a certain category is actually the list of its subcategories, so if some other data was available, it would've been put a sibling node to "categories".

Comment: `visible=true` doesn't look very reasonable to me as well, but it is how it is. Source: I've checked the implementation myself

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is very helpful.